# Sql issues when trying to upload using php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to upload a video to a folder which is working but, the relevant entry in the DB isn't occurring to match it. Really having trouble seeing what's wrong, as no errors are reported.

```
    session_start();
    require 'db.php';
    $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
    $uploader = $_SESSION['first_name'].$_SESSION['last_name'];
    $newstring = $_SESSION['last_name'].'_'.$_SESSION['first_name'].'_'.date('ymdhms').".mp4";
    $extension = strtolower(substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1));
    $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
    $max_size = '1073741824';
    $type = $_FILES['video']['type'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $date = date('Y-m-D');
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

    if(!empty($name)){
        $location = "uploads/";

    if($extension=='mp4'&&$type == 'video/mp4'){
        if($size <= $max_size){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$newstring)){ 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (file_name, upload_by, date) VALUES 
                   ('$newstring', '$id', '$date')";
                mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                require('profile.php');
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Upload Successful!";
                header('Refresh:0; url=profile.php');
            }else{
                $_SESSION['message'] = "File failed to upload";
                header("location: error.php");
            }
```

I'm not getting a corresponding DB entry. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `if($extension=='mp4' && $type == 'video/mp4'){` put space in `and` condition

Comment: I assume the `$mysqli` database connection variable is in the `db.php` file, can you include it in your question.

Comment: I am getting my upload successful message and it appears in the folder correctly named. Just the DB entry doesn't work

Comment: @MCMXCII
This is the $mysli connection. It appears to work when I query it elsewhere     

 `$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);`

Comment: Do other queries work within this file using that `$mysqli` connection?

Comment: @MCMXCII yes and no. 
`$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE date='$udate'");`

I run this for a particular date and it provides the list as needed. Not working on other dates though.

Comment: Does it work if you use the above format within this file though, e.g. `mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);` with a different query?

Comment: @MCMXCII My only other query is my login one like this. `$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$uname'");`

Comment: Your query may be failing. Try `Y-m-d` instead of capital D, which is the 3 char day (Mon, Tue, Wed). Also, check for mysqli errors on the query itself.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: @aynber that was it the 'd'. I had changed it because I had another problem I was trying to fix. Thanks for the heads up on the injection. I'm clearly not an expert on this and I 've muddling my way through. This won't be rolled out anywhere live but as well to have it correct!

Comment: Glad that helped. Using prepared statements does more than just protect against SQL injection. It eliminates a whole host of quoting issues that can crop up. I've found it's prevented many a headache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO videos (file_name, upload_by, date) VALUES 
                   ('".$newstring."', '".$id."', '".$date."')";
```